# jQuery list of data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of editable lists which, on a press of a button should be transformed into some sort of data structure. When it has been turned into some sort of data I need to add duplicates together.

Example:

- 200g banana
- 100g apple
- 200g apple

Should be turned into a data list of some sort and should in the end look like this:

- 200g banana
- 300g apple

Here's my attempt:

```
//button click event
$(".calculate").bind("click", function(e)
{
    //get the correct parent of the button
    var parent = $(this).closest("#calc");

    //get relevant data
    parent.find(".options").each(function(index, element)
    {
        var opt1 = $(this).children(".opt1").children("input").val(); //weight
        var opt2 = $(this).children(".opt2").children("input").val(); //ingredient
    });
});
```

Basically I click the button and the above script finds all the relevant data.

How can I turn this into a multidimensional array or a list of objects I can search for duplicates in?

When I try to make a dynamic object it seems to fail and when I make a multidimensional array to search in I get blocked by inArray's inability to search through them.

**Problem recap:**
I am able to get the user data no problem. Turning it into a list and adding together duplicates is the problem.

Comment: Could you put it on http://JSFiddle.net for us?

Comment: Can you show a sample of your html too, so we can get a better idea of what's going on. Preferably, put together a simple jsfiddle.net to illustrate the problem.

Comment: The `closest("#calc");` implies duplicate IDs used, say its not true.

Comment: Don't worry Mark, it is only there until I clean up the code and add a class instead.

Comment: +1'ed just for the Carly Rae Jepsen reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I will suggest you to have a global object that will contain the summary, this will look like this:

```
$(".calculate").bind("click", function(e)
{
    var fruits = {};

    //get the correct parent of the button
    var parent = $(this).closest("#calc");

    //get relevant data
    parent.find(".options").each(function(index, element)
    {
        var opt1 = $(this).children(".opt1").children("input").val(); //weight
        var opt2 = $(this).children(".opt2").children("input").val(); //ingredient

        // here is my code
        if(fruits[opt2] == undefined) {
            fruits[opt2] = opt1;
        } else {
            // assuming that opt1 is an integer
            fruits[opt2] += opt1;
        }
    });

    // use fruits variable here
});
```

Comment: You should be careful about where you declare the resulting object. If you set it as a global, on every click the quantities will add up. You should at least reset the variable in the handler.

Comment: This seem to work for making the data list! But there is no check to see if an element is already in the list, and if it is, add them together.

Comment: look at `else` statement, there is a += operator

Comment: Ah..on second run the value is NaN - must be a bug on my side, thank you for the help!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TLH6n/2/

in my case it works perfectly, I just changed the part where I need to get opt1 and opt2

Comment: Try clicking the button two times. It doubles the value in the object. It may or may not be what you want. If you only want to parse the inputs and get the result, declare the variable in the handler or re-initialize it there.

Comment: @AlexCiminian, yes I agree that your answer is more clever, but I believe that the goal of SO is not finding a complete solution for others' problem, but to help them to unserstand what they do wrong and find the final solution themselve, my answer just gives an idea how can this problem be solved

Comment: @haynar, you're right about SO, but variable scope is not obvious to JavaScript beginners. Your answer is as good as mine, minus the variable initialization issue. If you edit your answer and fix that, I'll remove the downvote. Cheers! :)

Comment: I've fixed that :) you're right, I don't know why I havn't considered editing my answer

Answer (score 4):

Here's another variant, which also does some simple parsing in case you have `100g` as input, versus `100`. Also, the data structure gets reinitialized every time, so everything does not get doubled on every click.

```
$(".calculate").bind("click", function(e)
{
    //get the correct parent of the button
    var parent = $(this).closest("#calc");

    var ingredients = {};

    var extractWeight = function (input) {
        // you can add other logic here
        // to parse stuff like "1kg" or "3mg"

        // this assumes that everything is
        // in grams and returns just the numeric
        // value
        return parseInt(input.substring(0, input.length - 1));
    }

    //get relevant data
    parent.find(".options").each(function(index, element)
    {
        var opt1 = $(this).children(".opt1").children("input").val(); //weight
        var opt2 = $(this).children(".opt2").children("input").val(); //ingredient

        // initialize to 0 if not already initialized
        ingredients[opt2] = ingredients[opt2] ? ingredients[opt2] : 0;
        ingredients[opt2] += extractWeight(opt1);
    });
});​
```

Here are some tips:

- `{}` is called an object literal and is used to create a new empty object
- object members can be accessed dynamically through the `[]` notation (i.e. if `x === "name"` then `o[x] === o.name`)
- variables are visible inside functions that are at the same level or deeper in the scope - like in my example I use `ingredients` in the `each` function.
- arrays in JavaScript only support numeric keys, so you won't have stuff like PHP's "associative arrays". Objects fill this gap in JS.

Comment: Thank you for the help, harynar's answer was closest at helping me with my problem, but your explanation was also very helpful. Unfortunately I cannot mark two as Answers so I'll rate yours up and thank you instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a jsFiddle that does what you're looking for :) http://jsfiddle.net/LD9TY/

It has two inputs, one for the item name and the other for the amount. When you click add, it checks an object to see if the item was already added. If so, it increments the amount for that item based on your input. If not, it adds that item with the amount you specified. It then goes and builds a ul with all the items in your "store".

Note that this is a quick and dirty example, so there is no type checking or validation going on :)

Comment: It is a very nice Fiddle Jason; However it does not solve the actual problem of creating and sorting through a data list. I appreciate the answer though and someone else is very likely to find use of your example! :)